# How to change an ExtJS component's renderTpl after it's been initialized?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am extending `Ext.button.Button` to add a notification bubble with a counter on it. I managed to do so by overriding `renderTpl`, but I want to be able to dynamically keep changing the renderTpl.

I tried using `doComponentLayout` after setting renderTpl, which the documentation claims to do the following:

> This method needs to be called whenever you change something on this
>   component that requires the Component's layout t...

[ExtJS 4.1 Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-doComponentLayout)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should pretty much never change the renderTpl. Secondly, once the component has rendered, it never renders again, the renderTpl is only run once.

Comment: So how can I update the counter without refreshing the browser? Is it possible?

Comment: Add your own method to your class, `updateCounter`, grab the DOM element that you're storing the counter in, change the `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you @EvanTrimboli, can you please add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your own method to the button that gets the child element and updates the DOM, for example:

```
Ext.define('MyButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',

    updateCounter: function(count) {
        // Grab a child element with class counter.
        this.getEl().down('.counter').update(count);
    }
});
```

Comment: I added an id to my div in `renderTpl`, like this: `<div id="{id}-counter" ...`, and updated it like this `Ext.fly(me.id + '-counter').update(count)`. Which is faster/better? Thanks

Comment: @Is7aq The documentation for `Ext.fly` answers this: "Use this to make one-time references to DOM elements which are not going to be accessed again either by application code, or by Ext's classes."

I believe Evan's answer is also faster and better in the long-run because it is starting its search in the current component's element and *only* looking inside it, whereas `Ext.fly` seems to be looking through the whole DOM, but I'm not all that familiar with `Ext.fly`.